# Why do I get 'Could not resolve the subpath “{slug}” after trying to add a category select to a Neo field?

Tags: categories, craft-pro, plugin-neo

I tried to add a Category Select field into a Neoblock but when i first saved the entry I received the following error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Could not resolve the subpath “{slug}”.

I removed the Neo Block with the Category Select but the error persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `{slug}` set for any of the settings in the fields inside of Neo?

Comment: Yes, @BradBell, i have a field using Categories to filter entries via the Categories fieldtype in a neo subblock. That field is saved and visitors can see final page, but no more changes can be saved.

It began when I tried to use the same Category for a second, different filter on this page. Reverting DD, template files have not fixed the issue. Even trying to remove the data associated with the original usage of the Category has not helped (because i can't save it).

Thank you.

![screenshot.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yv2e9fhzmy8vik/neo-categories.png?dl=0)

Comment: Update: recreating the page 1 block at a time, it seems this issue is also happening when i try to add an Asset.

Comment: @BradBell Hi, will changing `{slug}` to `{owner.slug}` affect data previously entered while using `{slug}`?

Comment: Currently using v 2.6.2980

Comment: Yeah, my guess is you need to update that to `{owner.slug}` and after making that change, you'd need to re-save any existing entries using that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed `{slug}` altogether from an Asset field definition.